# counting json object element jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have this json object

```
Object {casenum: "2015-7-001", month: "7", casenature: "1", resolution: "Mediation"}
Object {casenum: "2015-7-001", month: "7", casenature: "1", resolution: "Conciliation"}
```

I am counting the number of resolution for every month and also counting the number of casenature. In this example since the casenum is the same it means that the case is only so i only need to add one to case but because they appear twice in the array it is counted two times same with the casenature. I only want to count his only once since it is the same case. I count the resolution like this

```
var Monthcounter = 0;
var Civilcounter = 0;
var Criminalcounter = 0;
var Mediationcounter = 0;
var Conciliationcounter = 0;
var Arbitrationcounter = 0;
for (var obj in data) {
    console.log(data[obj]);
    var month = data[obj];
    var casenature = data[obj];
    if (month.hasOwnProperty('month')) {
        Monthcounter++;
        if (month.resolution == "Mediation") {
            Mediationcounter++;
        }
        if (month.resolution == "Conciliation") {
            Conciliationcounter++;
        }
        if (month.resolution == "Arbitration") {
            Arbitrationcounter++;
        }
        if (casenature.hasOwnProperty('casenature')) {
            if (casenature.casenature == "1") {
                Civilcounter++;
            }
            if (casenature.casenature == "0") {
                Criminalcounter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. How can i count casenature once for every casenum.
   Any idea is appreciated.

`UPDATE`

```
    var oneArray = [];
//Your code
if (casenature.hasOwnProperty('casenum')) { //Your bool check
    oneArray.push({
        casenum: casenature.casenum
    }); //Add obj to the array
    console.log(oneArray);
    var hasNum = false;
    $.each(oneArray, function(i, objOne) { //Each iterates through object in oneArray
        console.log(objOne.casenum);
        console.log(casenature.casenum);
        if (objOne.casenum == casenature.casenum) { //Check casenum unique in dataset 'data'
            console.log("");
            hasNum = true;
            return false; //Break iteration, need only 1 negative to break loop
        }
    });
    if (!hasNum) { //Only add counter if casenum is unique in dataset
        if (casenature.casenature == "1") {
            Civilcounter++;
        }
        if (casenature.casenature == "0") {
            Criminalcounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add each object of nature 0 or 1 into separate arrays, iterate through these new arrays each time you wish to add a counter to Civil/Criminalcounters and check the current casenum property vs all the casenum properties in your arrays. Slightly annoying nested array iteration, but it would function.

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling my problem would be how to check if this specific casenum have been used to increment the case nature.

Comment: I posted an answer with code described in the above comment. You can use and slightly change it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two arrays to use in this scope to check whether you have added a counter via an object with a casenum already.

Depending if you wish to add counters to unique casenums only, or casenum AND casenature must be unique, you will structure your nested `if(){}` logic.

```
for (var obj in data) {
    var zeroArray = [];
    var oneArray = [];
    //Your code
        if (casenature.casenature == "1") { //Your bool check
            oneArray.push(obj); //Add obj to the array
            var hasNum = false;
            $.each(oneArray, function(i,objOne) { //Each iterates through object in oneArray
                if (objOne.casenum == obj.casenum) //Check casenum unique in dataset 'data'
                {
                    hasNum = true;
                    return false; //Break iteration, need only 1 negative to break loop
                }
            });
            if (!hasNum) //Only add counter if casenum is unique in dataset
            {
                Civilcounter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: let me study the code it is a bit complicated for me at the moment

Comment: this is what i came up with but i still get 2 iteration can you take a look at update